# shape the notch with shaded colors using CSS -- Updated question with a better solution if you want to apply any borders to the notch

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to shape the `.notch` with shaded colors using css and try not to disturb any other elements.

```css
.cardContainer {
  height: 180px; 
  background-color: ghostwhite; 
  max-width: 400px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
.notch {
 display: initial;
 width: 200px;
 height: 25px;
 float: right;
 background: linear-gradient(149deg, slategrey, slategrey 16%, coral 20%, coral 80%);
 transform: skewX(64deg);
 transform-origin: top right;
 box-shadow: 0 0px 3px 2px coral;
 border-left: 2px solid white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 138px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="notch"></div>
  <div class="content">SAmple Card</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You mean like that above image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out.

```css
.cardContainer {
  height: 400px; 
  background-color: darkgray; 
  width: 400px;  
  align-self: center;
}
.notch {
  height: 15px; 
  width: 175px;
  float: right; 
  background-color: #30394A; 
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, darkgray 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0),  linear-gradient(90deg, #676767 10%, #9a9a9a);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(204,221,255,0.15);
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="notch"></div>
  <div class="content">Sample Card</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to get till here but I am trying for the multi color notch

Comment: Thanks a lot but if you notice the notch in the corner you could see two colors one is light grey occupied 80% of the notch and other 20% dark grey

Comment: So how do you want them to be? @Feroz

Comment: I will add one more picture above please take a look

Comment: @Feroz yea I saw. So what's the difference?

Comment: the notch should be of two colors light gray and dark gray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220598/discussion-between-feroz-and-ava).

Comment: @Feroz the answer has been updated. Idk if you would get notified in chats.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.cardContainer {
  height: 400px; 
  background-color: darkgray; 
  width: 400px;  
  align-self: center;
}
.notch {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: #30394A;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%), linear-gradient(10.81deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 82.11%, rgba(48,57,74,0) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(204,221,255,0.15);
  float: right;
  border-top: 30px solid #30394A;
  border-left: 59px solid transparent;
  transform: skew(50deg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="notch"></div>
  <div class="content">Sample Card</div>
</div>
```